# I have react project and get error when i want to build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, package.json, portfolio

I push a project to [github](https://github.com/ssadeghh/portfolio) and it come with npm run dev but when I want to get build with npm run build i get ***Failed to compile*** and some other error like:
info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element.
at makeWebpackError (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:308185)
at C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:105236
at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:13:28771), :34:1)
-- inner error --
Error: Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element.
at C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\static\css\c4db30214b074e73.css:645:3
at Root._error (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:79280)
at Root.error (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:125323)
at Parser.error (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:87626)
at Parser.expected (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:93960)
at Parser.pseudo (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:90128)
at Parser.parse (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:93483)
at Parser.loop (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:93048)
at new Parser (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:79137)
at Processor._root (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:96064)
at Processor._runSync (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:96571)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
Error: Expected a pseudo-class or pseudo-element.
at C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\static\css\c4db30214b074e73.css:645:3
at Root._error (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:79280)
at Root.error (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:125323)
at Parser.error (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:87626)
at Parser.expected (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:93960)
at Parser.pseudo (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:90128)
at Parser.parse (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:93483)
at Parser.loop (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:93048)
at new Parser (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:79137)
at Processor._root (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:96064)
at Processor._runSync (C:\Users\sadegh\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\cssnano-simple\index.js:190:96571)

> Build failed because of webpack errors

Comment: Sorry, but you have to provide some **details**. **Failed to compile** error can be anything. Can you please provide the error message? I believe that's enough reference to understand your problem...

Comment: Although, your question is a bit vague to give proper solution, I would suggest checking this : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/troubleshooting/#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify

Comment: i edit the context and wrote all of the error